Linux server is unable to boot properly
My Linux server is unable to boot properly due to a missing filesystem. How do I resolve it?


Please add the full error. Only a part of the screen is visible. Also, which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Only fully supported releases of Ubuntu (standard support) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

You've not specifically mentioned what Ubuntu product & release; but you've tagged a release that reached EOSS years ago, and is thus off-topic.   If you're using something else; please correct your details & tell us.  FYI:  I/O errors are usually hardware related

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's standard support life thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is community support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.

Ubuntu 16.04.6 Xenial
